# How to insert value with radio button in laravel 5.2?

Tags: controller, laravel-5

I create 3 input field in `users` table.
That is

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4"><b>Your role</b></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="teacher" value="Teacher" name="role" required><b>Teacher</b>
          </label>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="student" value="Student" name="role"required><b>Student<b>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="administrator" value="administrator" name="role"required><b>Admin<b>
            </label>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my insert format is

```
$role ->role=$request['role'];
```

I think my insert format is wrong. If it is wrong what will be the correct format?

Comment: Explain the error? Is the role's value not being passed to the request?

Comment: There is no error. all data insert without role.

Comment: What does `dd($request->all());` produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$role->role = $request->input('role');
```